# Fire parent click event when child is clicked in windows form user control

Tags: user-controls, delegates, event-handling, click, windows-forms-designer

I have a user control

```
    public partial class ButtonControl : UserControl
```

which has two controls of label and picturebox

```
        this.pictureBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
        this.text = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
```

I have used this control in a windows form

```
this.appointmentButton = new DentalSoft.UI.Controls.ButtonControl();
```

created an event

```
            this.appointmentButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.appointmentButton_Click);
```

[image]

but the problem is, if i click on the image or the label inside of the control, the click event doesn't fire. 
I want to fire this click event no matter where the user clicks inside of the control. Is it possible?

Answer (score 8):

Yes it is a simple matter.  When you click on the child controls they receive the click event and the user control does not.  So you can subscribe to the child control click events and when they occur simply raise the usercontrol click event and it will appear to click no matter where the mouse is positioned.

Just double click on the picturebox and the label to create the click event handlers then add a line of code to call the parent usercontrol OnClick method.

```
    private void text_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.OnClick(new EventArgs());
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.OnClick(new EventArgs());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem the following way. I wanted to changes the background images of the parent PictureBox when the child Label was clicked. I played around some and found I could call the event handler in the following way.

```
    private void Label_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label label = (Label)sender;
        Box_Click(label.Parent, e);
    }


    private void Box_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //
        PictureBox box = sender as PictureBox;

        //
        if (isMine[int.Parse(box.Name)])
        {
            box.Image = Image.FromFile(@"..\..\images\BoxRedX.jpg");
            MessageBox.Show("Game Over");
        }
        else
        {
            box.Image = Image.FromFile(@"..\..\images\BoxGray.jpg");
        }
    }
```

As you can see I grab the Child and using it to reference its parent and send it to the parents click event. This is the code I used to work in my project. The important method is the first on listed. The second is there for clarity to see how it passed and worked.